# Receiver app registration - exact format

Tags: url, chromecast

I'm trying out my first receiver app for ChromeCast, having some problems with what goes into the registration form. (very little help info there)

I am hosting my sender **index.html** and **bar_receiver.html** in 
**mydomain.com/foo directory**

To be able to run the receiver app, I have to register my device and the application on the developer console. Now to my questions:

**1) What exactly goes into the URL field for the Custom receiver?**

The sender is for the Chrome extension, so I've checked the Chrome platform check box

**2) Is that necessary?**

When I check that box, I'm asked for the "Web site url"

**3) What shoud go here? Is it the doc root url, http://mydomain.com, or something else.**

Answer (score 0):

1. In your case, the URL field will be https://mydomain.foo/bar_receiver.html.
2. The [x] Chrome isn't necessary for development.  When you deploy, it would be helpful to know where the official location for your sender is.
3. The root URL should be enough for now, we hope to provide additional clarification soon.

Comment: Actually, I would prefer if you were to enter the full url for (3); we can always extract the domain from the full url, but not the other way around. I have a short comment in this post on this particular area: https://plus.google.com/u/0/113893485258408261722/posts/Ss6CPtoErgN

Comment: To elaborate on the web case, your web app may have 10 different pages, all of which relevant to chromecast; what is recommended to put there in that box is the full url to your "landing" page, the page that people go to when they access your web application.

Comment: Thanks guys! That makes it crystal clear!
URL's are tricky, if you don't know what exact format should be used.
Now, that many more developers try their first application, it would be a good thing to have an example at the registration page.